# How can I decrypt data encrypted with 'rijndael-128-cbc' in ruby

Tags: php, ruby, encryption

I need to decrypt data which is encrypted by php with 'rijndael-128-cbc' algorithm.

Now I have a problem to convert php code to ruby code.
ruby OpenSSL::Cipher doesn't support rijndael-128-cbc then I use "aes-128-cbc".
I heard AES is based on the Rijndael cipher, so I guess I can convert decryption with rijndael-128-cbc' to AES-128-CBC.

```
enc = OpenSSL::Cipher.new "AES-128-CBC"
enc.encrypt
puts enc.key_len
```

It's output is 16

However, In php

```
echo mcrypt_get_key_size('rijndael-128', 'cbc')
```

this gets 32

Is there any difference between 'rijndael-128' and "AES-128-CBC"?

and How can I convert rijndael-128-cbc descrytion to ruby?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am no Ruby developer, so I can't help you with the ruby code, but I can give you a few pointers about Rijndael, and PHP's mcrypt extension ...

Yes, AES is based on Rijndael-128 and therefore Rijndael-128 and AES-128 are the same thing.

It's important to note that the number in Rijndael's variations refers to the cipher's *block size*, while for AES - it's the *key size*, so (for example) Rijndael-192 is NOT AES-192; AES always has a block size of 16 bytes or 128 bits.

That being said, Rijndael-128 can also be AES-192 and AES-256, the difference being only the key size.

As described in the PHP manual for `mcrypt_get_key_size()`, the function returns the *maximum* key length for the supplied cipher ...

```
AES-256 == Rijndael-128 with a 32-byte key
```

This is why it's returning 32. For AES-128, the key size is of course 16 - you can hardcode that.

Hopefully, that will clear it up a bit for you.